Empty diagram row has a tiny little line in the beginning
I have a dynamic diagram in my Excel sheet. Sometimes, one data row can be empty. But Excel keeps drawing a tiny tiny little row. Almost not visible.
Here is a screenshot:

The n on the left side is the number of entries, the diagram itself is the average of the entries. So, with n > 0 it works as expected.
But is n = 0, there is a tiny little colored "bar". More like just a line.
How do I remove that line?
Also, depending on the zoom, the bar is bigger/smaller.
For example here with a zoom of 140%:

The line for n=0 is almost as big as the one for n=1. Can be very confusing

Rather than 0 try swapping 0 for =NA() so it returns an #N/A error and isn't plotted.

I tried it, but does not work. The tiny line is still plotted

These are basic Excel charts you're showing aren't they? The tiny lines are series in the chart, or are they error bars or something else?
